# atom - How to replace in Atom without replacing some part of the search?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

Let's say I have these lines in a file:

```
This and an child
That and a entrepreneur
These and a banana
This and an cookie
```

And I want to replace all `an` and `a` that are incorrect.
I can use `an [^aeiou]` or `a ^[aeiou]` to find all the incorrects (I think, I'm not good with regexp).
What I want is to replace the incorrects using these expressions without changing the letter after the `a`/`an`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Using a positive lookahead `an(?= [^aeiou])` or a capturing group `an ([^aeiou])`. Latter replacement string should be like this `a \1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a [capturing group, `(...)`,](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and then include that in the replacement

---

Search:

```
an ([^aeiou])
a ([aeiou])
```

Replace:

```
a $1
an $1
```